# Flat button in expanded widget not being rounded properly

Tags: flutter, dart

I added a button to my appbar to act as a link to my search page and I wanted to add rounded corners but it's not rounding fully for some strange reason.

```
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            child: FlatButton(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(Icons.search),
                  Text("view 1"),
                ],
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                // something
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.nfc),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ],
    ),
    elevation: 6.1,
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
  ),
```

What I wanted - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1koiHKZXuvs57Qo6fDlhhm5jOC7N_IM1w/view

What I got - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZNsRQSk4rtMOIMtUy1IxyO_xTGT7KjGT/view

Comment: Why do you use ClipRRect widget?

Comment: use shape property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlatButton has a shape property that you could use to achieve what you want, check this solution

```
AppBar(
        title: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: FlatButton(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60)),
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(Icons.search),
                  Text("view 1"),
                ],
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                // something
              },
            )),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.nfc),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
        elevation: 6.1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove ClipRRect widget and add an attribute

```
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
   borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
)
```

to your `FlatButton` widget